# First link in the unlisted links is not working

Tags: html

I have entered the following code.

```
<body style="background-color:#FF9966;>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></a></li>
        <li><a href="#Category">Category</a></a></li>
        <li><a href="#Offers today">MyDeals</a></a></li>
        <li><a href="#Branded">Branded</a></a></li>
        <li><a href="#Register">Sign Up / Login</a></a></li>
        <li><a href="#Basket">My Basket</a></a></li>;
```

However, the following tag was entered on the later part style="background-color:#FF9966;>; After entering this, the first link in the unlisted links is not working. Please help. I am a novice

Comment: please provide your css or html code or put the code in jsfiddle section

Comment: You are missing an end quote after the ; - also several invalidities in the HTML but the quote gives the missing first LI

Comment: @mplungjan There are many more problems beyond this typo.

Comment: Not that gives that symptom

Comment: Please edit the title to match it to the content. Also paste your css or html code as well.

Comment: @captainblack it is all there. CSS and HTML and the error is obvious. I removed the irrelevant text from the title

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML code has several problems, including:

- You are closing your anchor tags twice, for some reason
- You never close the `<ul>` unordered list
- You never close the `<body>` tag, or at least it is not showing
- You are missing a closing quote in the `style` attribute in the `<body>` tag

Try the following snippet:

```
<body style="background-color:#FF9966;">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Category">Category</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Offers today">MyDeals</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Branded">Branded</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Register">Sign Up / Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Basket">My Basket</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Please do not answer typo questions. instead close as typo. It is not useful to anyone but the OP

Comment: @mplungjan Closed, neither of us can bang it shut though, need 3 more people ^ ^

Comment: The reason I answered is because it was clear from the quality of code (and 1 point rep level) that the OP would never figure it out unaided.  But maybe closing the question would force them to give a better one next time?  I never am too sure about these things.

Comment: Now it for sure needs more close votes because of your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

`"background-color:#FF9966;`

should be

`"background-color: #FF9966;"`

But you should really put style in an external CSS file.

Comment: Please do not answer typo questions. Instead vote to close

Comment: Hey thank you all, I missed a simple expression" and lost everything. Now it's fine. Thank you all for everything. I never knew that posting a query here would really work so fast.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with your HTML syntax, it should be like this

```
<body style="background-color:#FF9966;">
```

Comment: Please do not answer typo questions. It was already answered in my comment

Answer (score 0):

please use the body tag style:

```
<body style="background-color:#FF9966;">
```

Use your style code in your external stylesheet that will be a better option to get the result.

Comment: You were not clear it was a typo. And as such should not be answered

Comment: sometimes we used inline style so the user needs the required solution. ok now i will change my answer